# elastic search: filter the documents and then return only the source without any additional content

Tags: elasticsearch

Hi im new to elastic search, currently im using

```
curl -XGET 'http://blah/blah/_search?pretty=True' -d '{
"query": {
    "filtered": {
        "filter": {
            "range": {
                "time": {
                    "from": "2014/02/11 00:00:00", "to":"2014/02/12 00:00:00"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}'
```

but it will return me sth like this:

```
{
  "took" : 1,
   "timed_out" : false,
   "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 2,
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [ {
      "_index" : "blah",
      "_type" : "blah",
      "_id" : "blah",
      "_score" : 1.0, "_source" : {
        "blah" : [...<the contents that really useful to me>..]
```

the additional headers is redundant to me and will cause troubles, the only thing i need is the contents under the "_source". From the official ES blog i discover that

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/twitter/tweet/1/_source'
```

will return a "clean" _source, but in practice, i will not know the _id for my documents, and I will not be able to use the filter in that form (if any one know how to please tell me). so is there anyway that I can filter my documents and return a "clean" result that only contains the contents of the "_source"?
Thanks!

Comment: I'm confused what are you trying to do here? The response is verbose and informative and can be manipulated in a 'post process' to get you what you want. With ES not having any security, having a middle layer between your cluster and your UI is appropriate to handle this, what it appears to be, business rule-level manipulation.

Comment: Which language are you using? If parsing the answer from REST Api is difficult for you, perhaps there already exists a library that does it.

Comment: thanks for the comments, currently im using python to do this, I have a middle layer to extract the info i need, but it is not very efficient and im trying to get rid of it.